# emit signal when value of Qdoublespinxbox changed inside customDelegate

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, emit

i have subclass qstyleditemdelegate

in col==1 and col==2 i have create Qdoublespinxboxs, i want to emit valuechanged of my

Qdoublespinxbox, to calculate a subtotal ( col1 * col2 )

means : ouside the delegate

every time the value of Qdoublespinxbox changed i will update the value subtotal

Comment: Specifying a C++ tag might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add signal to your QStyledItemDelegate subclass, emitted in *setModelData()* reimplementation. Signal should have information about new value and possible locate of data. In other class catch that signal and update the value subtotal.

Comment: i have used this  unlockRow(int row) signal, i have emitted the signal in setModelData()  reimplementation but i get an error          C:\test\ex1\customtableselldelegate.cpp:114: error: passing 'const customTableSellDelegate' as 'this' argument of 'void customTableSellDelegate::rowUnlocked(int)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     emit rowUnlocked(index.row());
                                 ^

Comment: define signal like this:
 `signals:
    void unlockRow(int row) const; `

Comment: Yes thanks it works, and is short code :) , but i wanna know what really make diffrence betteween  void unlockRow(int row) and void unlockRow(int row) const ;

Comment: a const function can call only another const function(s), signal is also a function but you don't implement it (Qt moc will do)

Answer (score 5):

Create a slot in your delegate class:

```
void My_delegate::valueChanged() {
  emit commitData(sender());
}
```

In `My_delegate::createEditor` connect spinbox's `valueChanged()` signal to `My_delegate::valueChanged`.

Be sure that `setEditorData` method is implemented properly in your delegate class. In this method you should set model's data based on spinbox's value. This method will be called automatically when you emit `commitData`.

Now when user edits a spinbox, data comes to the model immediately. You can use the model's `dataChanged` signal to track data changes.

Comment: i tried your methode  i get error in this line      emit commitData(sender());   C:\test\ex1\customtableselldelegate.cpp:129: error: invalid conversion from 'QObject*' to 'QWidget*' [-fpermissive]
     emit commitData(sender());
                            ^

Comment: Use static_cast to convert QObject* to QWidget*.